# Booting Dell PowerEdge T300 without front panel

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, electrical-power

There is a front control panel on the board with a header. I do not have this and I want to boot up the server. I need to know where the power switch pins are so I can switch it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the hardware manual on dell website.

With it I can see it seem a special connector for the front control panel, and it's not documented. Can you just order a front control panel?

http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t300_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf

See item #22 there.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I am going to put it into a different case so there will be nowhere for the control panel to go. I just need to know the two pins so I can put on a normal power switch cable to.

Comment: Sadly if its not documented only a dell rep can answer you, as major brand usually do that to make part for them only. the front panel control can be removed on the other hand with 2 screw, you could put it with velcro on your next cover, as the part seem only 1inch large

Comment: thanks for your help, I am thinking my best option might just be try poking around with a screwdriver and hope it turns on.